# how much gross profit does the retailer earns

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question is

> A retailer sells widgets for $\$120$ each, which is $20\%$ more than they
> cost from wholesales. How much gross profit does the retailer earn
> after selling $8$ widgets
>
> $\$ 140$
>
> $\$ 148$
>
> $\$ 160$
>
> $\$ 172$
>
> $\$ 176$

After some calculations, I get $\$192$ which in not in the answer list.

I dont know. Please correct me if I have just made a mistake in the middle.

Thanks

Comment: Mind showing your calculations so we can see where you went astray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first figure out what the retailer pays for a widget. Call this price $x$.

We're told that $120$  is twenty percent more that what the retailer paid for a widget.  That is, $120$ is equal to $x$ plus twenty percent of $x$.  Since twenty percent of $x$ is $.2x$, this gives us the equation 
$$120=x+0.2x,$$
or
$$
120=1.2x.
$$ Solving this equation gives $x=100$ dollars.

So, the retailer pays 100 dollars for a widget and sells it for 120 dollars; thus
the retailer makes a twenty dollar profit for each widget sold.

So if he sells eight widgets, then his total profit is...

Answer (score 0):

Let $x$ denote the profit of one widget. We can write an equation to find this:

$$(120-x)(1+.2) = 120$$
$$(120-x)(1.2) = 120$$
$$120 - x = 100$$
$$-x = -20$$
$$x = 20$$

Since we want to know how much the retailer makes for $8$ widgets, we can simply say that his net profit is $8x$ which would be $8(20)$ = $\$160$.